# Will my Android device change to Gingerbread when I factory reset it?

Tags: factory-reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will factory resetting my device remove the Android upgrade?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12626/will-factory-resetting-my-device-remove-the-android-upgrade)

I have read over other people's questions and happened to stumble upon someone whose device had downgraded back to Gingerbread when they did a factory reset it. Will that happen to my tablet since I have an Android tablet and am looking to reset it also?

Comment: "Gingerbread instead of Android" makes no sense. Gingerbread is just the code name for one version of the OS, just like subsequent versions Ice Cream Sandwich and Jelly Bean.

Comment: I explained this as part of my [answer to your other question](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/34509/16575), please look it up there.

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to tell exactly what you're asking (due to what Al mentioned in the first comment), but it *sounds* like your question is answered by the linked duplicate. A factory reset does not modify anything at the OS level, such as the version of Android that you have installed. It erases user data/apps.